# Python: if a word contains a digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that will take a word as a parameter and will look at each character and if there is a number in the word, it will return the word

This is my string that I will iterate through
'Let us look at pg11.' 
and I want to look at each character in each word and if there is a digit in the word, I want to return the word just the way it is.

```
import string

def containsDigit(word):

    for ch in word:
        if ch == string.digits
        return word
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, update it as answer

Answer (score 11):

```
if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in word):
    print word, 'contains a digit'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work use the `in` keyword (which will check if an item is in a sequence), add a colon after your if statement, and indent your return statement.

```
import string

def containsDigit(word):

    for ch in word:
        if ch in string.digits:
            return word
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Regex?

```
>>> import re
>>> word = "super1"
>>> if re.search("\d", word):
...     print("y")
...
y
>>>
```

So, in your function, just do:

```
import re
def containsDigit(word):
    if re.search("\d", word):
        return word
print(containsDigit("super1"))
```

output:

```
'super1'
```

Comment: @"why not use regex?" -> because regex is the wrong tool for everything, except for things that only regex can do.

Comment: I think that iCodez is trying to say that there's no need to use a Bazooka when a rifle works just fine.  (To be explicit: bazooka==regex, rifle==python's string methods).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon:

```
for ch in word:
    if ch.isdigit(): #<-- you are missing this colon
        print "%s contains a digit" % word
        return word
```

Comment: That fixes the obvious syntax error, but it's still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Often when you want to know if "something" contains "something_else" sets may be usefull.

```
digits = set('0123456789')

def containsDigit(word):  
    if set(word) & digits:  
        return word

print containsDigit('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desperately want to use the `string` module. Here is the code:

```
import string
def search(raw_string):
    for raw_array in string.digits:
        for listed_digits in raw_array:
            if listed_digits in raw_string:
                return True
    return False
```

If I run it in the shell here I get the wanted resuts. (True if contains. False if not)

```
>>> search("Give me 2 eggs")
True
>>> search("Sorry, I don't have any eggs.")
False
```

## Code Break Down

## This is how the code works

The string.digits is a string. If we loop through that string we get a list of the parent string broke down into pieces. Then we get a list containing every character in a string with'n a list. So, we have every single characters in the string! Now we loop over it again! Producing strings which we can see if the string given contains a digit because every single line of code inside the loop takes a step, changing the string we looped through. So, that means ever single line in the loop gets executed every time the variable changes. So, when we get to; for example 5. It agains execute the code but the variable in the loop is now changed to 5. It runs it agin and again and again until it finally got to the end of the string.